# printf the ascii char % sometimes gives c and not %

Tags: c, ascii, printf

I am a little bit confused about how printf treats ascii characters.

When I print the character % like this, I get a correct response like "ascii %", and this is fine.

```
printf("ascii %%   \n");
printf("ascii \x25 \n");
printf("ascii %c   \n", 0x25);

ascii %
```

And I can put them on the same line like this, and I get "ascii % %", 
and that is also fine.

```
printf("ascii %c \x25 \n", 0x25);

ascii % %
```

But I can't do that in the other order since then I get c and not %, like this "ascii %c"

```
printf("ascii \x25 %c \n", 0x25);

ascii %c
```

What is happening?

However I noticed that it seems like printf treats \x25 like the normal % sign, 
since if I add another % directly after the output (\x25%) it becomes what I expect.

```
printf("ascii \x25% %c \n", 0x25);

ascii % %
```

But then I also noticed that printing a single % also seems to work, 
but I did not expect it to.

```
printf("ascii %  \n");

ascii %
```

Why did this work, I thought that a single % was not a valid input into printf...
Could someone clarify how printf is supposed to work?

---

Note: I am using the default gcc on Ubuntu 12.04 (gcc version 4.6.3).

Comment: Great question!  Don't you get a warning for `"ascii %  \n"`?

Comment: "\x25 %c" gives "warning: conversion lacks type at end of format [-Wformat]", but that is related to the space since "\x25%c" compiles without any warning.

Comment: No. It is not related to the space, at least not directly. Indeed, when `printf` sees the first `%` it starts to interpret the formatting sequence. The space can be valid within a formatting sequence for numbers or strings, so the space is accepted. But then, no further format character is found (d, x, s, ...) showing the warning. On the other side, when there's no space, then the formatting sequence is simply made of two consecutive percent, and thus is valid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C strings syntax, the escape character `\` starts an escape sequence that the *compiler* uses to generate the actual string what will be included into the final binary. Hence within C source code "%" and "\x25" will generate exactly the same character strings in the final binary.

Regarding the single `%`, this is an malformed format string. It results in undefined behavior. Therefore

```
printf("ascii \x25 %c \n", 0x25);
```

is actualy exactly the same as

```
printf("ascii % %c \n", 0x25);
```

It results in undefined behavior. There's nothing more to do, trying to understand what's happening with single percent characters is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, printf does treat \x25 like the normal % sign, `printf("ascii %  \n");` works because the `%` is at the end of the format string (ignoring whitespace).

Comment: WRONG: `printf` does never see the `\x25`.

Comment: So it is the preloader that converts \x25 into % so printf gets the same input during runtime?

Comment: @Johan No, it's not the preloader. It's the compiler that generates the same character array in the executable file.

Answer (score 1):

the format `printf("ascii \x25 %c \n", 0x25);`, since as you surmised \x25 is exactly the same as a '%' character, is {percent}{space}{percent}{c}. so, it prints a percent sign with a leading space, then a 'c'.

[edit: there is no leading space as I stated, since 'c' is not a numeric specifier]
[edit 2: the argument ", 0x25" is ignored since there is no matching specifier to use it]

Comment: Actually he seems to ignores that space in the middle so it becomes {percent}{percent}{c}, and then it is quite clear what it will become.

Comment: yes, that's what I tried to convey in my first edit, unsuccessfully it seems :^\